# Magento Admin Panel Login error

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-login

I got this error in my Magento admin panel login page and I don't know what's the issue.

[image: Login page]

Comment: Definitely something to do with Captcha. Did you make any changes to the configuration lately?

Comment: No, we didn't. Over the weekend. And when we try to open today that's the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reset your file `Mage_Captcha.xml`, so try to set the permissions on the folders with these commands:

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
sudo chmod 777 -R app/etc/;
sudo chmod 777 -R var/;
sudo chmod 777 -R media/;
```

Comment: also clear your cache and cookies for the site. you may be able to temporarily disable Captcha by editing your `Mage_Captcha.xml` file in app/etc/modules from `true` to `false`